# Android ExoPlayer set full screen on default play button clicked

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I tried to find out regarding `EXOPLAYER` more than 2 days about default play button. But now got stucks.

My question, is it possible to detect default play button when clicked?

I need to do the fullscreen mode when default play button clicked. I want when click play directly. No need another button.

```
defaultPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do the fullscreen mode
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use this method to do force fullscreen operations :

```
public void performFullScreenOperations(Boolean isFullScreen){
    if(!isFullScreen) {
        //fullscreenButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_fullscreen_open));

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);

        if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().show();
        }

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) playerView.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = params.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.height = (int) ( 200 * getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        playerView.setLayoutParams(params);

        //fullscreen = false;
    }else{

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

        if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }


        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) playerView.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = params.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.height = params.MATCH_PARENT;
        playerView.setLayoutParams(params);

        //fullscreen = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, as per my question, I need to do the fullscreen action by click default play. How?

Comment: @HiDayurieDave, just wanted to confirm wether the click default play, is that a play button you created customly, and the default play button can it be clicked several times or just once per video.

Comment: No, this is default play button from ExoPlayer

Comment: ok, not sure about the default play button but one workaround which can work is listen to onPlayerStateChanged, there check playbackState == Player.STATE_READY && playerview.player?.getPlayWhenReady()  && firstplay, if this condition is executed then make it full screen and make firstPlay boolean false.